# MarkLogic TDE: Not able to get data on multiple nested repeating fields and maps

Tags: marklogic, marklogic-9, tde, marklogic-10

I am working with TDE (Template Driven Extraction). I have an entity and trying to get data for repeating fields ( No Results) and valueMap (which is returning result in one line.)

```
<?xml  version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<entity>
    <status>Active</status>
    <instanceName>Instance1</instanceName>
    <entityName>Entity1</entityName>
    <entityfields>
        <entityfield>
            <entityfieldName>StringData</entityfieldName>
            <entityfieldType>string</entityfieldType>
            <stringValue>vikram</stringValue>
            <valueMap>
            </valueMap>
        </entityfield>
        <entityfield>
            <entityfieldName>ListData</entityfieldName>
            <entityfieldType>list</entityfieldType>
            <listValue>V1</listValue>
            <listValue>V2</listValue>
            <valueMap>
            </valueMap>
        </entityfield>
        <entityfield>
            <entityfieldName>TwoValListData</entityfieldName>
            <entityfieldType>twoValueList</entityfieldType>
            <valueMap>
                <entry>
                    <key>F1V1</key>
                    <value>F2V1</value>
                </entry>
                <entry>
                    <key>F1V2</key>
                    <value>F2V2</value>
                </entry>
            </valueMap>
        </entityfield>
    </entityfields>
</entity>
```

**TDE Template**

```
xquery version "1.0-ml"; 
import module namespace tde = "http://marklogic.com/xdmp/tde" 
 at "/MarkLogic/tde.xqy";
let $Entity_View :=
<template xmlns="http://marklogic.com/xdmp/tde">
 <context>/entity/entityfields/entityfield</context>
 
  
  <collections>
    <collections-and>
      <collection>entityinstance</collection>
      <collection>Entity1</collection>
    </collections-and>
  </collections>

 <rows>
   <row>
     <schema-name>main</schema-name>
     <view-name>entityView</view-name>
     <view-layout>sparse</view-layout>
       <columns>
       
          <column>
           <name>instanceName</name>
           <scalar-type>string</scalar-type>
           <val>../../instanceName</val>
         </column>
         
         <column>
           <name>status</name>
           <scalar-type>string</scalar-type>
           <val>../../status</val>
         </column>
         
         <column>
           <name>entityfieldName</name>
           <scalar-type>string</scalar-type>
           <val>entityfieldName</val>
         </column>
         
         <column>
           <name>entityfieldType</name>
           <scalar-type>string</scalar-type>
           <val>entityfieldType</val>
         </column>
         
          <column>
          <name>stringValue</name>
           <scalar-type>string</scalar-type>
           <val>stringValue</val>
           <nullable>true</nullable>
           <default>""</default>
         </column>
             
          <column>
           <name>valueMap</name>
           <scalar-type>string</scalar-type>
           <val>valueMap</val>
           <nullable>true</nullable>
           <default>""</default>
         </column>
         
          <column>
           <name>listValue</name>
           <scalar-type>string</scalar-type>
           <val>listValue</val>
           <nullable>true</nullable>
           <default>""</default>
         </column>
                               
       </columns>
       </row>
     </rows>
</template>
return tde:template-insert("EntityTest.xml", $Entity_View, (),"TEMPLATE")
```

While executing SQL query I am getting following result:

| main.entityView.instanceName | main.entityView.status | main.entityView.entityfieldName | main.entityView.entityfieldType | main.entityView.stringValue | main.entityView.valueMap | main.entityView.listValue |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Instance1 | Active | StringData | string | vikram |  |  |
| Instance1 | Active | TwoValListData | twoValueList |  | F1V1F2V1F1V2F2V2 |  |

I want valueMap data in different columns and listValue Data which I am not able to extract.